# Flutter check if TextField has focus

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how to assert if a specific TextField has focus or not.
The following code fails because it is saying `focusNode` is `null`. ( I cannot edit the Widget code itself )

```
    final fooKey = Key('foo');
    final barKey = Key('bar');
    final namePage = MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                key: fooKey,
                autofocus: true,
              ),
              TextField(
                key: barKey,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    testWidgets('Should focus on fooTextField not barTextField', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(namePage);
      expect(tester.testTextInput.isVisible, true);
      final fooField = find.byKey(fooKey).evaluate().single.widget as TextField;
      final barField = find.byKey(barKey).evaluate().single.widget as TextField;
      await tester.enterText(find.byKey(fooKey), 'I am a foo');
      expect(fooField.focusNode.hasFocus, true);
      expect(barField.focusNode.hasFocus, false);
    })
```

Comment: same issue here, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus#focus-a-text-field-when-a-button-is-tapped) first you need to create an instance of the FocusNode and then add it to TextField.

Comment: I can try, but you can follow the link, it has nice explanation with example.